# How can I upgrade Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 10.10 in one step?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Without having to upgrade to each major release. The upgrade manager wants me to go to 9.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to, though, you can change your /etc/apt/sources.list file to point to the new repositories and then run the following:

```
sudo sed 's/jaunty/maverick/g' /etc/apt/sources.list -i & sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Just because it can be done doesn't mean it's a good idea. If this is a workstation you wouldn't mind reinstalling if you had to, go for it. If it's a VM you can take a snapshot of beforehand, go for it. If it's a production server or has important date that isn't backed up, take a backup and don't do it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. And if you could you definitively should not be doing this. Ubuntu trys to bother you as least as possible with reboots and stuff. The few times are needed.

There is a reason why it is done exactly that way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by pacey and Jeff, I'm not sure if it would be a good idea, if at all possible.

I followed the steps in the tutorial linked below, so far it seems to have worked perfectly, although I would recommend taking a backup before you attempt it...

http://echenh.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-server-904-to-910.html